# How to make Sharepoint website running in VMware virtual machine accessible from host?

Tags: windows-server-2003, networking, vmware-workstation, nat, port-forwarding

I have a Sharepoint website that runs on IIS inside VMware Workstation guest system.
The host is Windows 7, whereas guest is Windows Server 2003.

What I basically need is **just to be able to browse the website from the host OS**.

I guess this has something to do with setting up NAT and port forwarding but I can't figure how to make it work. I tried setting Network Adapter in VM settings to NAT option but had no luck whatsoever.

**Update**
There's also a different kind of problem here: my VM computer name is used by another computer in our network. I cannot change it because it would ruin Sharepoint configuration (already tried), and reconfiguring Sharepoint is something I want the least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully solved the problem.
These are the steps I had to take:

1. Set **Network Adapter** mode to **Host-only** in VM settings.

[image]

2. Disconnected and connected **Network Adapter** in VM settings.
3. Run **ipconfig** in guest command line to find out VM's IP.
4. Edited **hosts** on host system to map this IP to machine name (*this also solved name ambiguity*)

[image]

***Voila***!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set up VMWare to bridge the network connection so your virtual machine appears as any other machine on the network. Configure it for DHCP or static IP, browse to the (virtual) machine, and you should have access.

Comment: How do I do it? I have nearly 0 experience with configuring the network. I also discovered another problem with names, I'll update the post to reflect it.

Comment: You might have to google for vmware workstation bridged network and find a link that works, but this might work: http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_configurations_changing_bridged_windows.html

Comment: It might also be in your help files for networking (look for bridged instead of NAT.)

Comment: Don't know about your computer name dilemma; http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261986.aspx May help. Other alternatives; rename the other computer, or post it as a separate question on SF and see if some sharepoint gurus can chime in.